# Clarifying Bayes' Rule

Tags: probability, bayesian

Looking through the literature  dedicated to Bayes factors I noticed that given formulae are quite unclear from the point of Kolmogorov probability axioms.

E.g. consider the following expression [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_factor#Definition):
$$
\Pr (M \mid D) = \dfrac{\Pr (D \mid M) \Pr(M)}{\Pr(D)} \ , 
$$
where $D$ stands for our sampled data, $M$ - for the *model*.

Well, $D$ is a random variable. But how should I interpret $M$? In applications, e.g. solving a hierarchial probabilistic model I can consider $\Pr (D \mid M)$ as the conditional density under given parameter. But the concept of $\Pr(M)$ seems rather misleading to me.

Are there any papers with formal definitions based on axiomatic approach?

Comment: $Pr(M|D)$ is interpreted essentially the same as with RV's. This says, "what is the probability that the model is true (or false) given the collected experimental data."

Comment: but what does it mean speaking formally? What is the probabilty of model? Axioms speak about the probability as a measure on some $\sigma$-algebra. How to deal with models in this manner?

Answer (score 1):

Since a model of the distribution of a data set isn't in any strict sence an event, then $\mathsf P(\mathcal M)$ isn't strictly the "probabity that the model is true" in terms of a sigma-algebra interpretation.   (The development of Bayes' probability theory preceeded measure theory.)   The prior is more sensibly interpreted as a measure of "our expectation for the truth of the model", or "our confidence in the model."

Assigning values to the prior is somewhat problematic, which is why Bayes' factor is a comparator that cancels the term.

Comment: Considering Bayes' factors is definitely self-worth. But I wonder if any strict probabilistic model model may be applied to Bayesian reasoning.

Comment: However, I've read [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978406/between-bayesian-and-measure-theoretic-approaches) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2310252/bayesian-probability-and-measure-theory) and now I feel like it's a case of two different axiomatic approaches. But it's still unclear if Cox's plausibility may be modeled by Kolmogorov probability